# How I can do replace correctly for Url?

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a code with switch language on site.
When url type is: `site.com/ru/rumanya-test` . 
 My code replace a `rumanya-test` with `mdmanya-test`. How I can prevent this, without add slash on language?

My code:

```
if ($lang == 'ru') {
   $ru_href = 'javascript:void(0);';
   $en_href = str_replace("/ru", '/en', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $md_href = str_replace("/ru", '/md', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $logo_href = '/ru/';
} elseif ($lang == 'en') {
   $ru_href = str_replace("/en", '/ru', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $en_href = 'javascript:void(0);';
   $md_href = str_replace("/en", '/md', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $logo_href = '/en/';
} else {
   $ru_href = str_replace("/md", '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $ru_href = '/ru' . $ru_href;
   $en_href = str_replace("/md", '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
   $en_href = '/en' . $ru_href;
   $md_href = 'javascript:void(0);';
   $logo_href = '/';
}
```

Comment: You can fiddle around with regular expressions or you could simply replace `/ru/`.

Comment: instead of `/ru` use `ru/` and son on for others

Comment: I can't add: `/ru/`. I need only `/ru`

Comment: Why can't you add `/ru/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` with only first occurrence of match should be replaced.

```
$md_href = preg_replace('#/ru#', '/md',  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: It is important to note that the reason this only replaces the first occurrence is because of the '1' passed as the last parameter. If you omit the 1 it will replace all occurrences.

Comment: @PeterMeadley example?

Comment: $md_href = preg_replace('#/ru#', '/md',  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); Would replace all instances

Comment: All working correctly. Example you can give with url?

Answer (score 0):

If you are always going to keep the same url format (eg. domain/[language]/page) then there are a couple of options I can think of.

**Option 1**
Instead of replacing "/ru", replace "/ru/"

**Option 2**
Split the url by the "/" and replace the 2nd element with the required language.

```
$url = rtrim("site.com/ru/rumanya-test", '/') . '/'; // Adds a slash at the end of the url if it doesn't already exist
$parts = explode("/", $url);

// If the URL contains language information
if(count($parts > 1)) {
    $newURL = $parts[0]."/en/".$parts[2];
}

// If it doesn't contain language information (ie. on the root domain)
else {
    // Your logic here
}
```

Note: This assumes that the language will always be the second element of your url.

Comment: But if user entered on site: example.com/ without lang? Default lang is: md

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can simply count the number of parts, if less than or equal to one, the user didn't specify a language in the url and therefore you can add your own logic to proceed in language md. Whether you append 'md' to the url or simply load 'md' localised content is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. Regular Expression is best solution for my situation.

Comment: I agree completely.